# Using decision tree regression and cross-validation in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am a novice in statistical methods so please excuse any naivety. I am having a problem understanding the execution of cross validation when using Decision tree regression from sklearn (e.g. DecisionTreeRegressor and RandomForestRegressor). My dataset varies from having multiple predictors (y = single dependent variable; X = multiple independent variables) to having a single predictor and consists of enough cases (> 10k). The following explanation applies for all cases.

When fitting and scoring the regressors with the standard methods:

```
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor()
rf = RandomForestRegressor()

dt.fit(X,y)
rf.fit(X,y)

dt_score = dt.score(X,y)
rf_score = rf.score(X,y)
```

The dt_score and rf_score returns promising R-squared values (> 0.7), however I am aware of the over-fitting properties of the DT and to lesser extent the RF. Therefore I tried to score the regressors with cross-validation (10 fold) to get a more true representation of the accuracy:

```
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor()
rf = RandomForestRegressor()

dt.fit(X,y)
rf.fit(X,y)

dt_scores = cross_val_score(dt, X, y, cv = 10)
rf_scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv = 10) 

dt_score = round(sum(dt_scores )/len(dt_scores ), 3)
rf_score = round(sum(rf_scores )/len(rf_scores ), 3)
```

The results of this cross validation always returns negative values. I assume they are R squared values according to the sklearn guidlines: ***By default, the score computed at each CV iteration is the score method of the estimator***  (the score method of both the regressors is R squared). The explanation given from the guidelines for the basic KFold cross validation is: ***Each fold is then used once as a validation while the k - 1 remaining folds form the training set.***

How I understand this, when using 10 old cv, is: my dataset is split into 10 equal parts, for each part the remaining 9 parts are used for training (I am not sure if this is a fit operation or a score operation) and the remaining part is used for validation (not sure what is done for validation). These regressors are a complete "black box" for me, so I have no idea on how a tree is used for regression and where the cross validation gets its R square values from.

So to summarize, I am struggling to understand how the cross validation can decrease the accuracy (R squared) so dramatically? Am I using the cross validation right for a regressor? Does it make sense to use cross validation for a decision tree regressor? Should I be using another cross-validation method?

Thank you

Comment: Cross validation is a technique to calculate a *generalizable metric*, in this case, R^2.  When you train (i.e. fit) your model on some data, and then *calculate your metric on that same training data* (i.e. validation), the metric you receive might be biased, because your model overfit to the training data. In other words, cross-validation seeks to estimate how your model will perform on *onseen data*. So, what this is telling you, if you are doing it correctly, is that your model will perform poorly on unseen data, likely due to overfitting.

Comment: As you state, DTs are notorious overfitters. You can try to tune the various parameters available to decision tree regressors in sklearn. A good place to start is usually the maximum depth.

Comment: So to summarize, the answer to "how the cross validation can decrease the accuracy (R squared) so dramatically?" is "because your model performs very poorly on unseen data".

Comment: Thank you for your inputs @juanpa.arrivillaga. Your comment "if you are doing it correctly", are you referring to how I am calling the sklearn methods in python? So you agree that it is completely conceivable that the the decision tree and random forest regressors over-predict so severely that it drops the R square from 0.8 to < 0 when applying cross-validation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have put together a small code-snippet articulating how on using DecisionTreeRegressor and cross-validation.

A. In the first code-snippet 'cross_val_score' is used. But, r2_score  might have negative score, giving insight about the poor learning by the model.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.20, random_state=0)

dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0, criterion="mae")
dt_fit = dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

dt_scores = cross_val_score(dt_fit, X_train, y_train, cv = 5)
print("mean cross validation score: {}".format(np.mean(dt_scores)))
print("score without cv: {}".format(dt_fit.score(X_train, y_train)))

# on the test or hold-out set
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print(r2_score(y_test, dt_fit.predict(X_test)))
print(dt_fit.score(X_test, y_test))
```

B. In this next section, using cross-validation for performing GridSerach on the parameter 'min_samples_split', then using the best estimator for scoring on the valiation/holdout set. 
    # Using GridSearch:
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
    from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

```
scoring = make_scorer(r2_score)
g_cv = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0),
              param_grid={'min_samples_split': range(2, 10)},
              scoring=scoring, cv=5, refit=True)

g_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
g_cv.best_params_

result = g_cv.cv_results_
# print(result)
r2_score(y_test, g_cv.best_estimator_.predict(X_test))
```

Hoping, this was useful.

#### Reference:

https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/75177/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score

Answer (score 0):

The decision tree splits on values of your features that generates a group with the highest purity. When I say purity, I mean in the sense that all the members in that group shares everything or almost everything that is similar (e.g. all white, age 35, all male, etc.). It will keep doing this until all your leaf nodes are perfectly pure, or certain stopping mechanisms are met (e.g. minimum number of samples in a node required to split). The parameters you'll see in the [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor) are basically those stopping parameters. Now, in terms of regression, what the tree will do is take the average of all true `y` of each leaf (the node that doesn't have anymore splits) as the estimated `y-hat` for that particular path, so that when you predict your test dataset, each record from that test dataset will basically follow some path down the tree until it hits a leaf node, and the estimated `y-hat` for that record will be the average true `y` of all observations in that leaf node.

A random forest is basically a collection of decision trees which use a subset of your training data to do the training. These trees are usually not as deep as a single decision tree model, which helps alleviate the overfitting symptoms of a single decision tree. The idea of a RF is that you're using many weak learners that can generalize your data well. Hence, less overfit.

The R-squared metric is basically `1 - (SS_res / SS_tot)`. Breaking that formula down, you're basically looking at the sum of squared residuals and the sum of squared total. Therefore, you just have to know the true `y` values, the estimated `y-hat` values, and the mean of the true `y` values, `y-bar`.

Comment: Thanks you for your explanation @Scratch'N'Purr. This adds to my understanding of the concepts. Is it in your opinion/experience possible then that the R square can drop from 0.8 to < 0 when applying cross-validation for decision tree regressors? Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, it is possible, considering how the sklearn's API has some default settings that create really really deep trees. If you look at the default settings for things like `min_samples_leaf` and `min_samples_split`, they suggest really deep trees. Even the `RandomForestRegressor` has those default values. I would suggest increasing those values.

Comment: You should also look into [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). This does a parameter search across possible values to get the optimal parameter values from the list of values that you supply in the grid search. For starters, just run a parameter search on `min_samples_split` and have `min_samples_leaf` set to 50. And use a random forest.

Comment: Great, thanks @Scratch'N'Purr, the high tree depth makes a lot of sense